# Cocos2d rotate and resize image and then add a mask

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, masking

Aloha!

I haven't found a good way to do this after a week of trying. Can anyone recommend to me a way in cocos2d that i can take an image and place a mask image over it for sizing guidance. Then have my users alter the pictures size and rotation with touches so that the image fits into the mask and then merge the images? I have seen this done so many times in apps but I can't quite get there.

A million virtual shekels and my first born camel for someone that can help with this.

Comment: what have you already done and was the problem ?